# Editing a txt with Java gives me troubles

Tags: java

I have a txt with a list of words. Every word that has 14 letters, starts with a "M" and has a "n" at the eighth position. Should be very simple, but there are actualy a few problems. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/users/admin/Documents/Auslese.txt"));
     BufferedWriter buff2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/users/admin/Documents/Eingegrenzt.txt"));
     String text = buff.readLine();
     char buchstabe, buchstabe2;

     while(text != null){
         if(text.length() == 14){
         buchstabe = text.charAt(0);
         buchstabe2 = text.charAt(7);
         if((buchstabe == 'M' || buchstabe == 'm') && buchstabe2 == 'n'){
             buff2.write(text);
             buff2.newLine();
         }}
         text = buff.readLine();
     }

}
```

There are actually a few words that match these conditions, but no word will be written in the second file after execution of the code.

For example the line `text.length() == 14` doesn't work, even though there are words with 14 letters. If I choose `text.length() > 13`, then it works.

Or the condition with the letter 'n'. Without it (and `length > 13`) it works fine, but after adding this line there are no words in the file again (even though for example every word starting with "Marathon" should be fine).

I hope, that somebody here can help me :/.

Comment: Does every line in the file only contain one single word?

Comment: Have you tried using `System.out.println()` to see what code is being run?  It should work if the input is as you say it is, but you may also want to use `buff.close();` and `buff2.close();` at the end of the main method

Comment: Try to **print the length**, print `buchstabe` and `buchstabe2`. Learn debugging. Set **breakpoints** to see what is happening - your IDE has powerful tools, so use them!

Comment: Or use the command line... `grep '^M......n' input.txt > output.txt` is what a unix wizard would do.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse it looks suspiciously like he's using Windows, from the `C:/users/admin/...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [closing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close--) the buffers. They might not be flushed, hence, nothing in the file. That's more or less how the `BufferedWriter` works.

Put `buff.close()` and `buff2.close()` at the end of your program.

Also, always close your buffers/files/streams within a `finally` block. That way it will always be sure the buffers are closed.